# Why God didn't make all males as circumcised?

Tags: allah, creation

If there is really a God or if He knows already that one will be his devotee so why didn't He made all devotees circumcised?

Answer (score -2):

God has already Angles, and God has created Jins before human who was corrupted as we are today. And he wiped them out, then God created Adam and gave life to us. Long story short, he sent us to the earth to test us to see how loyal we are and how good people we can be. We have choice to belive him or accept him as our Lord! So on judgment day he'll sent us where we belong. He is God he can do as he want, we should thanks God for we are alive and all that things he gave us. Just look at our body how complex it is, do you really belive out of nowhere someone made us that complex? I think not, there is our creator up there!

Comment: I believe in nature only. Before life there was only amiba so is also created by god?

Comment: What is an "Amiba"???

Comment: Perhaps [Amoeba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba)

Answer (score -4):

the Circumcision is not just a religious proccess .... but it healthy too ..and in the other hand imagine that the Muslims burnt and They are circumcised ... so the unmuslim poelpe will say that they can't be Muslims